# Unable to start nginx (and passenger) with RoR 3.2.3 on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm trying to make nginx and Rails 3.2.3 work together on localhost. I went through this instruction http://www.modrails.com/install.html. What I did is

```
gem install passenger
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

So it should be enough. Then I add

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.org;
        root /home/alex/RubymineProjects/psg;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

and, starting nginx, I got an error

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_enabled" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Before that nginx worked well, it shows `"Welcome to nginx!"` on `http://localhost`.
Your thoughts?

Comment: Are you running a previous installation of nginx or the one compiled through `passenger-install-nginx-module`? For a simple development server you can run `passenger start` in your project root folder instead.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to use nginx but only passenger or WEBrick.

Comment: Just run `$ passenger start` at the root of your rails project.

Comment: I want to use nginx only. Is your advice going to run nginx?

Comment: Yes, it will run nginx in [Passenger Standalone](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html) mode.

Comment: @Tanzeeb Khalili, you're wrong. Passenger Standalone mode means that nginx doesn't work.

Comment: No I'm not -- from the documentation: *It is powered by an Nginx core.*

Comment: but it's not exactly the same. What I need to is start nginx with Rails!

Comment: Then run the correct instance of nginx. `passenger-install-nginx-module` compiles its own version of nginx. Kill the nginx you are running now and run that one instead.

Comment: I can uninstall nginx, can't I? And Rails is going to keep working well with passenger only?